# How to add new items to SharePoint List using List.asmx native WebService and client object model?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I need to add items to a SharePoint list by using **client object model** and **Lists.asmx** web service.
How can this be achieved?

Also, I am not able to understand why do we use **Lists.asmx** web service when we can directly add items to SharePoint list using only client object model.

*Can someone kindly explain my doubts with an example?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class CreateListItem
    {
        static void Main()
        {   
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
            oListItem["Body"] = "Hello World!";

            oListItem.Update();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

There are certain scenario on when to use CSOM vs Services.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26093/webservices-or-client-object-model

> If you can you should use the Client Object Model (CSOM) - it does not
>   support that many features as the web services but are superior in a
>   number of ways such as:
>
> data types batching of commands (more efficient usage of bandwith)
>   optimization of data loaded (more efficient usage of bandwidth) more
>   similar to the server side object model in terms of programming (the
>   web services are in most cases just huge chunks of undocumented XML
>   you need to parse) ... So, for performance you will likely suceed
>   better using CSOM

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Madhur...! But I am asked to use both CSOm and Lists.asmx at the same time. Is it even possible? If so, can you please guide me how to use lists.asmx?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You either use CSOM or Lists.asmx. There are several examples on how to do it:http://toreinarsolli.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/adding-items-to-a-sharepoint-2010-list-using-web-service-api-2/ . Do that and post any issues in a new question.

Comment: Yeah...It is working great Madhur. Thank you so much for all your time and help :)